# npm install creating files at wrong directory for electron

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

When I install `sqlite3`by `npm` in directory of electron project,
it creates

```
c:\testing\Elektron\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64
```

but electron aplication throw following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\testing\Elektron\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
```

I tried to rename the directory, but it lead to

```
Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

[Here is the pastebing of all commands and actions I did](https://pastebin.com/J7s4iTDM)

I don't need work arounds, I need to build aplication later into an executable file, so I appreciate your answer.

Comment: What did you add/change to the main.js ?

Comment: const sqlite = require('sqlite3') addedd at line9

Comment: I also learned you don't use npm install on this, but differend specific electron install on this, I will look on it today and propably answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
electron-rebuild
```

is needed for native modules.